# How do I log in to Git Bash at the very beginning prompt?

Tags: git, authentication, command-line, git-bash

I am literally brand spanking new at coding. (Learning online how to become a Full Stack Developer) I am stuck at the command line prompt. It's not letting me log in. There isn't a place for me to even try to log in.

I am a Windows 10 user. And at the very top of the terminal box where it has the minimize, restore, close ... it says: **/usr/bin/bash --login -i**

Can you please help me? I am really stuck and cannot go any further. I'm not in a classroom setting, so I can't raise my hand and ask the instructor for help.

Thank you sooooo much!

With Gratitude,
Angela

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-bash Hope that is enough to get you on your track.

Comment: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/849 - *git bash hangs on open with /usr/bin/bash --login -i on top window bar*

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to log in; you're simply at a normal `bash` shell prompt.

The `--login` argument means that the shell you're using is a login shell.  What this means is not very interesting in a Windows environment, but it controls which files are read at startup and some other attributes of the shell process itself.

Since there's no login prompt, you just enter commands as normal and they'll be executed.  For example, you could type `echo foo` and that command would be executed, printing `foo` and a newline.

On a Unix system, you'd need to log in to access a prompt so the system knows what user to run commands as, but on Windows the Git Bash commands are simply associated with your normal Windows user account.

Answer (score 0):

You could try either of the below solutions:

1. Run Git Bash as administrator.
2. Disable Windows File Protection (WFP).